# Simple return value of the dropdown item from WebMethod from Ajax function using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod

I got two dropdownsddl1,ddl2 and a button btn on aspx page. When I click on button need to get the alert box showing the values of the selected items from both dropdowns.Can I know how can I do that from web method please...

**Button:**

```
<input  id="Test" type="button" value="clickme" onclick='<%# String.Format("showingddlvalues(\"{0}\")",Eval("ddl1ID")) %>' />
```

**Web method:**

*[WebMethod]*

```
    public static string showingddlvalues(string ddl1ID)
    {
        return String.Format("showing selected ddl1ID{0} value here ", ddl1ID);
    }
```

**jQuery:**

```
function showingddlvalues(ddl1ID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/showingddlvalues",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{ddl1ID:'" + ddl1ID + "'}",
        success: AjaxSucceeded,
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
}

function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    alert(result.d);
}

function AjaxFailed(result) {
    alert('error:' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}​
```

Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your jQuery & web method like this and check the result again:

**jQuery:**

```
function showingddlvalues(ddl1ID) {

    var value = $('#' + ddl1ID).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/showingddlvalues",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{value:'" + value + "'}",
        success: AjaxSucceeded,
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
}​
```

**WebMethod:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string showingddlvalues(string value)
{
    return String.Format("{0}", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

var js = $('#idOfDrop option:selected').text();

Or

var js = $("[name=nameOfSelect] :selected")

alert(js);

You will get the selected value from dropdown

Comment: Hi Abhi, Thanks for the quick response,I have pasted my code .will you please guide me how can I get the values of both dropdown items please...